# SharedPreferenses don't save states

Tags: android, android-listview, sharedpreferences, android-preferences

I need settings in application which will be available in few namespases(all are in one project). I desided to create class with methods like:

```
    private SharedPreferences prefs;
private Context context;

public Preferenses(Context context){
    this.context=context;
}

public void invertLanguageState(String lang){
    prefs=context.getSharedPreferences(LEARN_WORDS_PREFS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    boolean state=prefs.getBoolean(lang, false);
    Editor editor=prefs.edit();
    editor.putBoolean(lang,!state);
    editor.commit();
}

public void setLanguagesStates(String []langs,boolean []states){
    prefs=context.getSharedPreferences(LEARN_WORDS_PREFS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    Editor editor=prefs.edit();
    final int size=states.length;
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
        editor.putBoolean(langs[i],states[i]);
    }
    editor.commit();
}
public boolean [] getLanguagesStates(String []keys){
    prefs=context.getSharedPreferences(LEARN_WORDS_PREFS,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    final int size=keys.length;
    boolean [] states=new boolean[size];
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
        states[i]=prefs.getBoolean(keys[i], false);
    }
    return states;
}
```

then I try to use it for ListActivity, I wrote my adapter code:

```
   public class UsableLanguagesAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

private final Context context;
private final String [] values;
private boolean [] states; // language states in checkbox (select or not)
private Preferenses prefs;


public UsableLanguagesAdapter(Context context,String []values) {

    super(context,RProvider.getLanguageUserItem(),values);      
    this.context=context;
    this.values=values;
    this.prefs=new Preferenses(context);    
    this.states=prefs.getLanguagesStates(values);
}   

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View rowView = inflater.inflate(RProvider.getLanguageUserItem(), parent, false);

    CheckBox checkBox=(CheckBox) rowView.findViewById(RProvider.getLanguageItemCheckBox());
    TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(RProvider.getLanguageItemText());
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(RProvider.getLanguageItemImage());
    imageView.setImageResource(RProvider.getLangImageId(values[position]));
    textView.setText(values[position]);
    checkBox.setSelected(states[position]);     
    final int pos=position;
    checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

           @Override
           public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {
               Boolean state=prefs.getLangugeState(values[pos]);
               Log.d(state.toString(),"show state");
               prefs.invertLanguageState(values[pos]);
               state=prefs.getLangugeState(values[pos]);
               Log.d(state.toString(),"show state");
               ///checkBox.setSelected(isChecked);
           }            
    });
    return rowView;
}
```

}

but unforchantly when I reload activity, all check boxes are unchecked. Can you say me how to decide this problem? Also this result will be necessary in other activities.

Answer (score 1):

If  I have not misunderstood

```
checkBox.setSelected(states[position]);
```

you need to set the `checked` properties of your checkbox. `checkBox.setChecked(boolean)`

from the doc:

```
setChecked(boolean)
```

> Change the checked state of the view

Comment: @Abbath is states[position] a boolean?

Answer (score 0):

Problem was checkBox.setSelected(states[position]); insteed checkBox.setChecked(states[position])